# Why sys.maxsize.bit_length() is 63 and not 64 on my system?

Tags: python, theory, bit, twos-complement

I've recently learnt how to see the max integer int() that my x64 arch can deal with. (Above this number, the system uses long).
Now i'm studing bitwise operators, and learnt on this site that Integers in Python are stored in two's complement system.

when I type:

```
print sys.maxsize.bit_length()
```

I get 63 bits. I think that this depends on my machine arch (Ubuntu 64 bit). 
The questions are:

- where is the bit n°64?
- is it the leading 0 or 1 in the two's complement notation?
- why isn't included in the bit length?

Added:

- why for negative numbers we need 64 bits and not 63?

Answer (score 4):

Because on your platform the value is derived from a *signed* integer. The maximum value fits in 63 bits, leaving the 64th bit for negative values.

Note that the `int.bit_length()` method gives you the *minimum* number of bits required to represent *that specific integer* and doesn't ever include leading zeros. It doesn't say anything about the underlying C integer:

```
>>> 1 .bit_length()
1
>>> 2 .bit_length()
2
>>> 3 .bit_length()
2
>>> 4 .bit_length()
3
```

From the [`int.bit_length()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

> Return the number of bits necessary to represent an integer in binary, **excluding the sign and leading zeros**

`sys.maxsize` usually reflects the maximum value a [`ssize_t` C integer](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/) can hold, but it gives you a Python `int` object. The fact that the *C type* might use two's complement hardly matters to the Python type.

The source code merely [converts a C constant to a `int` object](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/71cb8f605f77/Python/sysmodule.c#l1432), the constant is defined in [`pyport.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/71cb8f605f77/Include/pyport.h#l182) and thus is platform dependent as to how that value is derived. For Linux that'll be:

```c
typedef ssize_t         Py_ssize_t;
/* ... */
#define PY_SSIZE_T_MAX ((Py_ssize_t)(((size_t)-1)>>1))
```

Clearly the value must be using a [two's complement signed number representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) for that last part to work; the value `-1` is shifted one bit to the right to come at the largest possible value; in *two's complement* -1 is represented as all 1 bits, shifting these to the right gives you a 0 and all 1s.

In the two's complement system of encoding it is the most significant bit (the left-most) that encodes the sign, so in a 64-bit number that leaves only the other 63 bits to encode the integer value.

Comment: why 64 for negative value? I'd like to understand this

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: I only mention it because `sys.maxsize` is determined from the maximum value the *C type* `ssize_t` can hold. It is *that* type that is a singed C integer; it doesn't matter what format it uses, but generally it'll use two's-compliment. **This is immaterial for the *Python* `int` object type**.

Comment: so why 63 and not 64 for positive values, and instead the computer uses 64 bits for a negative one?

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: how much do you already know about how two's complement works?

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: but please don't expand your question; you shifted from Python to two's compliment theory here.

Comment: Not so much. I'm quite confused, but i've read about a theorical infinite sequence of leading 1 for negative numbers, and of 0 for positive numbers

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: for Python integers this really doesn't matter; the `.bit_length()` method is a helpful method if you need to convert to binary or deal with binary formats, that's all. Your original question, why is it just 63 bits on a 64 bit machine can be answered with just that. If you have a broader question about two's compliment (which is what informs the C `ssize_t` maximum value), then read up on that on Wikipedia for the full theory on how that system is used to encode both positive and negative numbers in binary by using the most significant bit as indicating the sign.

Comment: Sorry for expanding my question, but i'd like a more- simplified answer. I haven't understood the last part of your answer at all. Can you give a short and simple answer to my 4 questions specifically? Thanks a lot and sorry but i'm learning with the whole english official documentation but i'm an italian boy and sometimes i need practical or simpy explanations.

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: Most of those questions are *not Python questions* but general computer theory, that is why I keep pointing you to the two's compliment Wikipedia article. Because the very first bit (the most significant) is used for the sign, and it is 0 for positive numbers and because the `int.bit_length()` method doesn't count leading 0s, you get 63.

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: and to be absolutely clear: for Python integers this all doesn't matter; how the underlying interpreter stores these doesn't matter at all. `sys.maxsize` happens to reflect a system value, but you really don't need to care how many bits are used for any given Python `int` object. The `int.bit_size()` value doesn't reflect that, it only counts *actual bits used*, not how many *could* be stored.

Comment: ok. That's the answer I'd have liked to see. So 64 bits are used to represent either 'sys.maxint'and '-sys.maxint()-1' (the largest and the smallest int number in python on 64 bits system), but when I print the first I get '0b111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111' (63 digits after b), while in the second i get '-0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' (64 digits after b). So in the first case the leading 0 is truncated in the representation but exist?

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo: exactly; and the reason Python is not giving you leading 0 bits is because Python doesn't necessarily use signed C integers to store these. In Python 3 all integers, and in Python 2 `long` integers are stored as an array of C unsigned integers with their sign stored elsewhere. The maximum number of bits this storage can hold is limited only by your memory.